# How to reduce width between UI components in my case UILabel and UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitextfield

I have a UILabel (space) UITextField. The UITextField is right aligned and whenever user enters in the field UITexField should reduce horizontal space between UILabel. Below line is from UIView which has equal width of UITextField. How can i achieve this with proper constraints without overlapping UILabel?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something like this?

<kbd>[image: 3 characters in text field, small width]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Many characters in text field, larger width]</kbd>

Here are the constraints you need:

[image: Diagram showing constraints needed]

Result:

<kbd>[image: Text field and green view expanding as more text is entered]</kbd>

[*Demo Repo*](https://github.com/aheze/TextFieldConstraintDemo/)

### Edit: Prevent text field covering label

You will need to:

1. Add a `greater than or equal to` constraint between the label and the text field
2. Set the label's `horizontal compression resistance` to a `751` instead of `750`.

[image: Add extra constraints]

I made this [video](https://youtu.be/jljO2YyW0mg) so you can follow along.

Result:

<kbd>[image: Text field expands as text is entered, but stops as soon as it hits the label]</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @aheze this works. Appreciate for images. How can i make sure that UITextField does not overlap UILabel?